# Python Regex for Clinical Trials Fields

Tags: python, regex, text

I am trying to split text of clinical trials into a list of fields. Here is an example doc: https://obazuretest.blob.core.windows.net/stackoverflowquestion/NCT00000113.txt. Desired output is of the form: `[[Date:<date>],[URL:<url>],[Org Study ID:<id>],...,[Keywords:<keywords>]]`

I am using `re.split(r"\n\n[^\s]", text)` to split at paragraphs that start with a character other than space (to avoid splitting at the indented paragraphs within a field). This is all good, except the resulting fields are all (except the first field) missing their first character. Unfortunately, it is not possible to use `string.partition` with a regex.

I can add back the first characters by finding them using `re.findall(r"\n\n[^\s]", text)`, but this requires a second iteration through the entire text (and seems clunky).

I am thinking it makes sense to use `re.findall` with some regex that matches all fields, but I am getting stuck. `re.findall(r"[^\s].+\n\n")` only matches the single line fields.

I'm not so experienced with regular expressions, so I apologize if the answer to this question is easily found elsewhere. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please post a small sample of the desired **output**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a positive lookahead instead of a negated character class:

```
re.split(r"\n\n(?=\S)", text)
```

Now, it will only match 2 newlines if they are followed with a non-whitespace char.

Also, if there may be 2 or more newlines, you'd better use a `{2,}` limiting quantifier:

```
re.split(r"\n{2,}(?=\S)", text)
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/1nIauL) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C2QUsr/1).

Answer (score 0):

You want a lookahead. You also might want it to be more flexible as far as how many newlines / what newline characters. You might try this:

```
import re
r = re.compile(r"""(\r\n|\r|\n)+(?=\S)""")
l = r.split(text)
```

though this does seem to insert \r\n characters into the list... Hmm.